# Return Values of #execute and #query methods of sqlite3 gem

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

I am working with sqlite3 database in ruby with the help of sqlite3 gem (I'm trying to gain a better understanding of using sqlite3 gem without the use of ActiveRecords). I have an sql query below:

`SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = 'Charles'`

From which I'm expecting it to return the value '5'

### execute

```
$db.execute('SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ?', 'Charles') do |result|
  puts result
end
```

Above will print '5', but will return an sqlite3 object. I couldn't seem to get the `execute` method to *return* the value '5'.

### query

```
$db.query('SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ?', 'Charles') do |result|
  result.first.first
end
```

The closest I could get is to use the `query` method to return the value '5' (above), but this requires `.first.first` which seems convoluted.

Is there a better way for me to get the value I needed? i.e. perhaps through accessing the sqlite3 object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
$db.results_as_hash = true
$db.execute('SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ?', 'Charles') do |row|
  puts row['id']
end
```

You want a method. Make something like

```
def find_id_by_first_name(first_name)
  $db.results_as_hash = true
  $db.execute('SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ?', first_name) do |row|
    return row['id']
  end
end
```

But anyway, you could have a problem with your query. If `first_name` has not a unique index, this query could return more than one row. So this method doesn't make so much sense. This just returns the first matching result.

Comment: That did not work. I get an error: `TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer`

Comment: Have you executed this line
`$db.results_as_hash = true`?

Comment: ok, it no longer returns an error after `results_as_hash` is enabled. The puts work alright, but i would like to have the value '5' *returned* rather than printed. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`to_i`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/blob/e627e522cf2a71d1ad63ee76dfbcb0857082733c/lib/sqlite3/value.rb#L33):

```
$db.execute('SELECT id FROM contacts WHERE first_name = ?', 'Charles') do |result|
  puts result.to_i
end
```

The reason why you need to call `to_i` is, because the sqlite gem doesn't know the data type of the returned value. To identify the datatype it would need to make another query for the table definition for example. This is something that the sqlite gem doesn't do for you like an ORM like ActiveRecord would do.

Btw. you find the reason why `puts` returns the value too in the same files, because there is a `to_s` method defined that is called by `puts` on `result` when printing.