# Retrieving array from MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, ruby

> I'm not using sqlite3 gem
>   I'm using mysql2 gem

I'm retrieving data from MySQL database given that it meets the condition of a certain `event type` and `severity`. However, it returns only one row instead of an array of results. It really puzzles me. Shouldnt .map return an array?

```
   result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE event_type = 'ALARM_OPENED' AND severity = '2'") 
    equipments = result.map do |record| 
        [
            record['sourcetime'].strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
            record['equipment_id'], 
            record['description']
        ]
    end
    p equipments
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return Values of #execute and #query methods of sqlite3 gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919299/return-values-of-execute-and-query-methods-of-sqlite3-gem)

Comment: @JollyProgrammer I'm using MySQL not sqlite3

Comment: You are using DBI right? The interface should be the same for both databases.

Comment: @JollyProgrammer I'm not sure what DBI is, but one thing for sure is that I dont use $db in my code. I'm just querying MySQL using Ruby.

Comment: what is the connect object in your code? DBI stands for Database Independent Interface for Ruby.

Comment: @JollyProgrammer `connect = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "", :username => "", :password => "", :database => "")` This is my connect code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had misread your question...I think what you are looking for is in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41919299/return-values-of-execute-and-query-methods-of-sqlite3-gem).

**UPDATE**

You can use each instead, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'mysql2'

connect= Mysql2::Client.new(:host => '', :username => '', :password => '', :database => '')

equipments = []
result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE event_type = 'ALARM_OPENED' AND severity = '2'", :symbolize_keys => true).each do |row|
    equipments << [ 
                    row[:sourcetime].strftime('%H:%M:%S'), 
                    row[:equipment_id], 
                    row[:description] 
                  ]
end

puts "#equipments {equipments}"
```

EDITED:

I forgot to add .each at the end of the query. So it was returning the initialized empty array instead.

Comment: `pluck` is not Ruby Core, what do you `require` ?

Comment: Consider replacing this by a duplicate note.

Comment: How do I do that? I am new here :)

Comment: @Yunnosch What do you mean by that?

Comment: @JoshuaNg At the time of my comment, the answer just read "Look in this other answer", with a link. That kind of answer is unneeded and should be replaced by a flag as duplicate. The answer has changed now and seems now to contain more than just the link, which I assume is different from the linked answer. This answer can now be evaluated by its own content.

Comment: @JollyProgrammer I am not sure whether you are asking me about how to make a duplicate note. If you are, look at the little grey word "flag" right beneath the question. If you click it, you should have a choice of flags to put on the question. One of them should be "duplicate". Just read all the text around it for explanation.

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh, I got what you were trying to imply. Sadly, the question in the link does not provide the answer. It's for sqlite3 gem while my code uses mysql2 gem

Comment: @JoshuaNg I tried not to judge your question (which is out of my area of sufficient knowledge) I just recommended the answerer to mark as duplicate if *they* think your question is. Now it seems that the answerer needs more input (or hints) to improve the question, in order not to risk downvotes. (Again I refrain from downvoting for lack of knowledge, but if the link is not helpful and the code fails basic expectations...)

Comment: @JoshuaNg I forgot to add .each at the end of the query. Please check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must need to change your sql statement :

```
result = connect.query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE event_type = 'ALARM_OPENED' AND severity = '2'", :as => :array)
```

Comment: I get an error saying `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`. I tried adding `.to_s` but the error still persists

Comment: The problem with :as => :array is that it will return each row as an array. So when you try to get the values like record['equipment_id'] it tries to convert 'equipment_id' to an integer and crashes. Can you try to run the original query that you had with this line after: result.count?

Comment: @JollyProgrammer The count is 1